# SQL Trigger to insert/update sysdate after insert or updating tuple in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I've got the following database schema:

Movie (MovieID, Title, Year, Score, Votes) Actor(ActorID, Name, RecentDate)
Casting (MovieID, ActorID, Ordinal)

I'm trying to write a trigger so whenever I insert a tuple or update a tuple in the Casting table, the recent date value using SYSDATE should be updated in the Actor table for the actorid that is being used to insert or update a tuple in the Casting table.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER updateDate
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON CASTING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT RECENTDATE
FROM ACTOR
UPDATE ACTOR
SET RECENTDATE = SYSDATE
WHERE ACTORID = :new.ACTORID;
END;
/
```

I'm new to SQL and I know I probably could write this in an easier way.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Those tags don't look right. Are you using MySQL, Oracle, or what?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Oracle

Comment: You made it. This part `SELECT RECENTDATE FROM ACTOR` is unnecessary, delete it if you want sysdate in actor table.

Comment: This worked great! Thank you Ponder Stibbons